# Can I create or fake a second camera inside the scene in Spark AR Studio

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I'm looking for a way to "mirror" or create an internal 3D camera in the scene, I'm attempting to rebuild a scene I've made using threejs ([hollowsights.org/heads](https://hollowsights.org/heads)) and I'm looking for a way to "render" a texture that is based on the device camera input and 3d elements I add to the scene.

Thanks,
nir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a nullObject

[image]

Then drag it down to empty space, it calls worldSpace.

[image]

So put all your scene inside this nullObject and it should work. Also you need to use a device with gyroscope. This will turn on DeviceMotion capability.